# Why does `x.cnn.com` resolve to 1.1.1.1 and 6.9.6.9?

Tags: networking, dns

Is there any explanation for the following behavior?

```
$  dig @8.8.8.8 x.cnn.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.1-P2 <<>> @8.8.8.8 x.cnn.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52259
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;x.cnn.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
x.cnn.com.      19  IN  A   6.9.6.9
x.cnn.com.      19  IN  A   1.1.1.1
    $  dig @8.8.8.8 x.cnn.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.1-P2 <<>> @8.8.8.8 x.cnn.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52259
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;x.cnn.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
x.cnn.com.      19  IN  A   6.9.6.9
x.cnn.com.      19  IN  A   1.1.1.1

;; Query time: 326 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 10 20:39:22 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 70
;; Query time: 326 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 10 20:39:22 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 70
```

Why would you point the domain at `1.1.1.1` / `6.9.6.9`? Is this some convention like `example.org`?

Comment: Nslookup also gives same result. See this:: http://geoiplookup.net/ip/6.9.6.9 and also https://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/6.9.6.9

Comment: Likely placeholders, though the .mil is pretty amusing.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `cnn.com` uses Amazon Web Services (AWS) -hosted name servers as their authoritative name servers for the general `cnn.com` domain:

```
$ dig cnn.com soa
[…]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
cnn.com.        76  IN  SOA ns-47.awsdns-05.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

…but those servers are configured to treat `x.cnn.com` (note, `x` is NOT a wildcard here, it is the literal letter 'x') as a subdomain, and queries for that subdomain are delegated to a different set of authoritative name servers: `dmtns[01-05].turner.com` (CNN is owned by Turner broadcasting):

```
$ dig @ns-47.awsdns-05.com. x.cnn.com
[…]
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
x.cnn.com.      86400   IN  NS  dmtns01.turner.com.
x.cnn.com.      86400   IN  NS  dmtns02.turner.com.
x.cnn.com.      86400   IN  NS  dmtns03.turner.com.
x.cnn.com.      86400   IN  NS  dmtns04.turner.com.
x.cnn.com.      86400   IN  NS  dmtns07.turner.com.
```

…and it appears those `dmtnsXX.turner.com` DNS servers contain 'A' records (name-to-IPv4-address mapping records) pointing `x.cnn.com` to `6.9.6.9` and `1.1.1.1`:

```
$ dig @dmtns01.turner.com. x.cnn.com
[…]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
x.cnn.com.      20  IN  A   1.1.1.1
x.cnn.com.      20  IN  A   6.9.6.9
```

I tried a few other `[a-z].cnn.com` domains and didn't discover any others that were set up the way `x` was.

I'm guessing `x.cnn.com` was some kind of internal testing sandbox among CNN/Turner's IT department that accidentally leaked out to the real world, but there's no way to know for sure.